# Run JBehave tests from a jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, bdd, jbehave

We have a suite of JBehave tests which we run on a scheduled job to health check a web service.

On every run, maven downloads dependencies and continues through the rest of its lifecycle before running the tests.

In order to speed up the test execution, is it possible to package the tests within an executable jar along with the associated dependencies and run that instead of using Maven?

Comment: I do not profess to be an expert on maven, but I believe maven should only be downloading dependencies if it detects that there is a change in the version number(s) of the affected dependencies in the pom.xml file, or if they are missing.  Are you certain that the dependencies are indeed actually being re-downloaded?

Comment: You're right Bill, Maven does this. However these tests run on a Jenkins build whose workspace is wiped on every run.